# Symbolic method, bijective proofs or double counting proofs?

Tags: combinatorics, proof-explanation, combinatorial-proofs, analytic-combinatorics

As you can see, I have been studying analytic combinatorics, specifically Flajolet's symbolic method.
And while I was reading about how combinatorial structures are translated into generating functions, the question arose as to whether this is a [bijective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijective_proof) or [double counting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_counting_(proof_technique)) proof. To contextualize I will give an example:

To count the number of binary trees with a fixed number of internal nodes, a symbolic expression of this type is obtained $\mathcal{T}=\{\square\}\cup(\{\bullet\}\times\mathcal{T}\times\mathcal{T})$, and assuming that $\mathcal{T}$ has the generating function $T(z)$ then this translates to $1+ z\cdot T(z)\cdot T(z)= 1+zT(z)²$. From this expression we obtain that

$\displaystyle T(z)=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4z}}{2z}$

and

$\displaystyle [z^n]T_n=\frac{1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}$,

and thus the number of flat binary trees with $n$ internal nodes is given by the nth Catalan number.

Does this type of reasoning correspond to a bijective or double counting proof? I can't get the answer clear.

Comment: My opinion: No, there is no bijection, so this does not constitute a bijective proof. Perhaps someone can prove me wrong?